# The Representation of $\mathbf{Sp}(V)$ on $V$ is irreducible?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

A symplectic form $\beta$ on $V$, a finite-dimensional real vector space, is a nondegenerate skew-symmetric bilinear map $\beta:V\times V\longrightarrow\Bbb R$. We define the symplectic group of $V$ as the following subgroup of $\mathbf{GL}(V)$:

$$\mathbf{Sp}(V)\overset{\rm def}{=}\{g\in\mathbf{GL}(V)\,\colon\,\beta(gu,gv)=\beta(u,v)\,\forall\,u,v\in V \}$$

Clearly $\mathbf{Sp}(V)$ acts on $V$ by left multiplication. I am trying to prove that this representation is an irreducible representation of $\mathbf{Sp}(V)$.

I am not sure how to approach this. I am new to Lie groups and their representations. Do I need to use, somehow, the existence of a symplectic basis (a basis of $V$ of the following form)?
$$\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n\cup\{f_i\}_{j=1}^n\quad \beta(e_i,e_j)=\beta(f_i,f_j)=0\quad\beta(e_i,f_j)=\delta_{ij}.$$

I think using this basis it is enough to prove that the standard action of $\mathbf{Sp}(2n,\Bbb R)$ which is when $V=\Bbb R^{2n}$ and $\beta$ is the symplectic form given by $$\begin{pmatrix}0&I_n\\-I_n&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: (classical-groups) and (symplectic-linear-algebra) would be good tags, at least better than (lie-algebras)

Comment: @blue I think Lie algebras is a fine tag here. Especially since the representation of Lie groups and Lie algebras is so closely linked (e.g. the rep is irreducible iff the corresponding Lie algebra rep is). Someone might ask the almost identical question in that scenario and any answer to one immediately answers the other as well. If anything I'd drop abstract algebra as it is a bit too broad

Answer (score 4):

You should try to prove something a little bit stronger: for any non-zero $x\in V$, there is a symplectic basis with $e_1=x$.

Then if $x,y\in V$ are non-zero, you can choose symplectic bases $\mathcal{B}=(e_1,\dots,e_n,f_1,\dots,f_n)$ and $\mathcal{B}'=(e'_1,\dots,e'_n,f'_1,\dots,f'_n)$ with $e_1=x$ and $e'_1=y$.

Then show that if some $g\in GL(V)$ sends $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{B'}$, then actually $g\in Sp(V)$, and that gives you a $g\in Sp(V)$ such that $g\cdot x=y$.

Use that to deduce that $V$ is irreducible. (The point of this proof is the important fact that a symplectic space, unlike a quadratic space, is *homogeneous*: all points are equivalent.)

Comment: All {non-zero} points are equivalent :)